# Confusion Matrix - What is my models recall score?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, decision-tree, confusion-matrix

Looking at a project and dont understand why both classes have a recall score when recall only involves the positive class? (converted is the positive class)

Code for the confusion matrix:

```
def metrics_score(actual, predicted):
    print(classification_report(actual, predicted))
    
    cm = confusion_matrix(actual, predicted)
    
    plt.figure(figsize = (8, 5))
    
    sns.heatmap(cm, annot = True,  fmt = '.2f', xticklabels = ['Not Converted', 'Converted'], yticklabels = ['Not Converted', 'Converted'])
    
    plt.ylabel('Actual')
    
    plt.xlabel('Predicted')
    
    plt.show()
```

[Confusion Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJKbt.png)

Which recall score is the correct measure for my model? I believe it is 86% but then the precision score would be 93%? But that doesnt make sense as the model is doing better on recall considering there are fewer false negatives than false positives 57 vs 224 (thats accounting for the ratio difference of having more not converted cases vs converted cases). What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: You say that "converted" is the "positive" class, but your model doesn't know that.  So, the recall scores you see are for whether you want "converted" to be positive or negative: it's arbitrary, so just pick the one you want.

Comment: @Him Ok I think I get it, please correct me if I'm wrong. But since I am choosing converted(1) as my True Positive then that row in the confusion matrix are my scores. So precision would be 62% and recall would be 86%?

Comment: I suspect that's what's happening.  Computing the precision and recall from the confusion matrix is just arithmetic: try computing them for both ways to assign "positive" and "negative" and see if you get the reported values.